# Endpoints NodeJs failed CSRF verification

Tags: node.js, api

Trying to automate some queries of the website https://sig.cdmx.gob.mx/sig_cdmx/# , the endpoint https://sig.cdmx.gob.mx/mapa/search_cuenta_info_pred.json but fails the CSRF verification; any idea how to handle it? I tried by using a previous request, and getting all data from it but didn't work... Code:

```
const https = require('https');

//make a first get request to obtain csrftoken and cookies

function getCSRFtoken(url){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get(url, (resp) => {
      let data = '';
      resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
      });

      resp.on('end', () => {
        //Save response to check it manually
        let fs = require('fs');
        const fd = fs.openSync("./tmp/csrf", "r+");
        fs.writeSync(fd, data.toString(), 0, 'utf8')
        
        //get csrfmiddlewaretoken to use it later
        let word = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken: \''
        let index = data.toString().indexOf('csrfmiddlewaretoken: \'')
        let tokenLength = 64
        let csrftoken = data.toString().slice(index, word.length + index + tokenLength).replace('csrfmiddlewaretoken: \'', '')
        let headers = {
          Cookie: []
        }

        //Save cookies for next query request
        //maybe the error is here??? not recreating the cookies correctly
        //also tried headers.Cookie = resp.headers['set-cookie']
        for (var i = 0; i < resp.headers['set-cookie'].length; i++) {
          let ck = resp.headers['set-cookie'][i].split(';');
          for (var k = 0; k < ck.length; k++) {
            if (ck[k].indexOf('token') >= 0 || ck[k].indexOf('incap_ses') >= 0) {
              headers.Cookie.push(ck[k].trim().replace(/=/g, ': '))
            }
          }
        }
        csrftoken = {csrftoken: csrftoken};
        resolve({headers, csrftoken})
      });

    }).on("error", (err) => {
      // console.log("Error: " + err.message);
      reject()
    });
  })
}

function post({url, postData, headers}){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    postData = JSON.stringify(postData);
    const options = {
      port: 443,
      method: 'POST',
      headers
    };
    const req = https.request(url, options, (res) => {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      let data = '';
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve(data)
      });
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
    });

    req.write(postData);
    req.end();
  })
}

async function getRealEstateInfo(data){
 let { csrftoken, headers} = await getCSRFtoken('https://sig.cdmx.gob.mx/sig_cdmx/#')
 data = {account: data, csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken.csrftoken}
 let h = await post({url: 'https://sig.cdmx.gob.mx/mapa/search_cuenta_info_pred.json', postData: data, headers, csrftoken})
}
setTimeout(async () => {
  let realEstateInfo = await getRealEstateInfo('00000000')
}, 1000)
```

The site uses 2 csfrtokens, one for the headers and one in the body data with the key `csfrmiddlewaretoken`.